# Toast Notifications Windows 10 with cppwinrt library

Tags: c++, windows-runtime

I  have found an example how make a Toast Notifications in Windows 10 on c++

https://github.com/WindowsNotifications/desktop-toasts/blob/master/CPP/DesktopToastsSample.cpp

In my opinion this code has C style rather than C++ which doesn't look very good to me.

I've found a wrapper over winrt for с++ https://github.com/Microsoft/cppwinrt

Now I am trying to write similar code like in the example but with winrt.

In example There are lines

```
ComPtr<IToastNotificationManagerStatics> toastStatics;
HRESULT hr = Windows::Foundation::GetActivationFactory(
   HStringReference(RuntimeClass_Windows_UI_Notifications_ToastNotificationManager).Get(),
&toastStatics);
```

I started writing code

```
#include "winrt/Windows.UI.Notifications.h"
#include "winrt/Windows.Foundation.h"
using namespace winrt::Windows::UI::Notifications;
using namespace winrt::Windows::Foundation;
void main() {
    auto igetaf = IGetActivationFactory();
    igetaf.GetActivationFactory(???);
```

1. How to convert string to winrt::hstring
2. How to convert RuntimeClass_Windows_UI_Notifications_ToastNotificationManager hstring

The documentation doesn't even say what strings I can use

learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.foundation.igetactivationfactory (Not enough reputation :()

Can you give me an example of working code. ?

Answer (score 5):

There are currently three main ways of consuming Windows Runtime classes from C++. First is using the ABI, which is [what you found](https://github.com/WindowsNotifications/desktop-toasts/blob/master/CPP/DesktopToastsSample.cpp). As you have discovered, it's very cumbersome.

Second is C++/CX, which uses the `^` symbol to represent Windows Runtime classes. [You can see an example of this style in the UWP samples repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/ExtendedExecution/cpp/SampleConfiguration.cpp#L32).

Third is C++/WinRT. In C++/WinRT, objects are represented directly as classes. There's [an introduction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt745094.aspx) and a [migration guide](https://github.com/Microsoft/cppwinrt/blob/master/Docs/Migrating%20C%2B%2B%20CX%20source%20code%20to%20C%2B%2B%20WinRT.md).

In C++/WinRT, you don't operate with class factories at all. (Hence no need to create an `hstring` for the class name, and no need for `IGetActivationFactory`.)

Covering all of C++/WinRT is beyond the scope of this site, but here's a sketch:

```
using winrt::Windows::UI::Notifications::ToastNotification;
using winrt::Windows::UI::Notifications::ToastNotificationManager;
using winrt::Windows::Data::Xml::Dom::XmlDocument;

XmlDocument doc;
doc.LoadXml(L"<toast...>...</toast>");
ToastNotification toast(doc);
ToastNotificationManager::CreateToastNotifier(L"appid").Show(toast);
```

Comment: can you please point us into the general direction of where we can find api user manual on using this?

Comment: @DusanJovanovic What "this" are you referring to? C++/WinRT? Or ToastNotificationManager. Both are documented on MSDN but in different places.

Comment: "this" is obviously this code in this answer ... cppWINRT usage to produce code that manages/displays notification icons and so called "toasts" ... in standard C++ at that ...

Comment: There are two aspects to the code: One is C++/WinRT, the other is the toast notifications feature. C++/WinRT is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/intro-to-using-cpp-with-winrt). Toast notification documentation starts [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/toast-ux-guidance).